# find command doesn't find directory in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, find

I have a shell script that is finding and copying files, which works just fine. However when it tries to find and copy a directory it is not working

```
#!/bin/sh
PROJECT_NAME=$1
HELM_BUILD_FOLDER="helm-build"
HELM_PROJECT_BUILD_FOLDER="$HELM_BUILD_FOLDER/$PROJECT_NAME

#find and copy all FILES from .helm/my-project to helm-build/my-project/project-values THIS IS SUCCESSFUL
find .helm/$PROJECT_NAME* -maxdepth 0 -type f,d -exec cp -av "{}" $HELM_PROJECT_BUILD_FOLDER/project-values/ ";"

#find and copy all diectories from .helm/my-project to helm-build/my-project THIS IS FAILING even though directories exist
find .helm/$PROJECT_NAME/* -maxdepth 0 -type f  -exec cp -av "{}" $HELM_PROJECT_BUILD_FOLDER/ ";"
```

I have tried several different means of fixing this. I've tried using execdir instead of exec, used cp -R. I tried to simply output the results of the directory find and nothing got output... it's almost as if it's not being ran.

Another weird thing is happening when i try to execute in the terminal. This works, despite $PROJECT_NAME not being defined outside of the script:

`find .helm/$PROJECT_NAME/* -maxdepth 0 -type d -exec cp -R -av "{}" helm-build/my-project/ ";"`

Comment: If you only process stuff in a single directory why don't you just use a glob?  `cp -aRv .helm/$PROJECT_NAME/* helm-build/my-project/`?

Comment: We have no idea what your directory structure looks like, and you are not telling us exactly what the failure is.   If you don't think it runs prefix it with a echo so you know what does or doesn't run.

Comment: Either $PROJECT_NAME is set or it is not.  `env |grep PROJECT_NAME` will tell you.

Comment: Putting `set -x` at the beginning of the script will get you an execution trace, showing (among other things) how those wildcards are expanding.

Comment: @BenZifkin Can you give us some feedback? Maybe a more in depth description of what you wish to accomplish?